# Where should I add binary executables in an Android project?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

So, I have this native code that I built for different CPUs. I don't want to load as a library, I want to execute the binaries through runtime.exec(...).

Is there a way of placing them in some place where Android will take care of the CPU qualifiers? Or do I have to make different APKs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making different APKs is sometimes a good choice, to reduce the download size. *Just think about it, hundreds of thousands of people will be downloading these extra megabytes from the Play Store with every update!* There are some strategies for creating and maintaining such split APK's: it's important to keep the version numbers in proper order. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20029256/192373 and the improvement by *[Ashwin S Ashok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2767181/ashwin-s-ashok)* below.

Whether you choose to split the APK's, or keep a monolithic one, feel free to use my *"patent"*: put your executables into `libs/armeabi-v7a` (or other subfolder, according to target ABI) , and give them names that all start with ***lib*** and end with ***.so*** (e.g. `lib_vim_.so`). This will turn on the installation magic, and the appropriate files will be unpacked (and updated) into your `/data/package/lib` folder with executable permissions.

Answer (score 4):

`Android Q+` (Personally tested with `Android 11`). Since got released new policy changes towards android system safety, you can't execute normally your binary executables just from `/data/data/package/files/...` folders.

**W^X violation details:**
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10#execute-permission

`Solution:`

**1. Add your executables to the native libraries folder in Android studio eg.** `app/libs/armeabi/executable`.

[File structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHLU1.png)

**2. Also add this line to your manifest (Application layer):**

```
<Application
...
     android:extractNativeLibs="true">
...
</application>
```

If you are using newer version of the Gradle plugin, you may face issues when
your executable not being packaged into apk or extracted in.

`/data/app/package/lib/.../...`

---

You need then trick Android Gradle plugin a bit.

`Solution:`

**1. Create a folder structure in your file explorer** `lib/armeabi/executable` *(I use armeabi just as an example, it can be your architecture)*

**2. Now zip this `lib` folder and rename it to** `yournaming.jar`

**3. Copy and paste in your Android Studio** `libs` **directory**

[should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H5e4.png)

**4. Go to your `build.grade(app)`, in `dependencies` section add following line
for compiling** `.jar`.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    ...
}
```

**5 Build your `.apk` and check with `analyze tool`, folder should be now created in `.apk` itself**

If all these steps done, now can try do exec command to run binary executable from android app:

```
try {
    // creating exec process
    Process process = 
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir + 
"/executable");
    // reading and printing executable outcome
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            process.waitFor();
            process.getInputStream().read(buffer, 0 , buffer.length);
            System.out.println(new String(buffer));

} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) 
{
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hopefully helped to solve your case