# Can I make Eclipse build a different APK for different devices

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk

In an application I have made, there are some device-specific native libraries -- for example, there is one library for Snapdragon-based devices, another separate library for Tegra-based devices, and yet another for generic implementations (if no platform optimizations are available).

These libraries can get pretty big due to some specific optimization tradeoffs we made (and because there's debug symbols in the libraries). What's the strategy to have Eclipse only bundle one of the libraries into the resulting APK, depending on what target is being deployed for? For example, if I deploy onto my phone, it should deploy only the Snapdragon variant, but if I deploy onto the tablet, maybe it deploys only the Tegra variant. This would speed up development a lot!

Thanks!

Comment: Might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954156/android-build-separate-apks-for-different-processor-architectures

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Android Studio and Gradle. Gradle build flavors and variants give you the ability to do what you want. You can read about that [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants).