# SoLoader$WrongAbiError with React Native Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, crash, react-native

Recently we've integrated react native into our app with just hello world view. On some devices (mostly Asus) we're getting this crash.

```
Fatal Exception: com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader$WrongAbiError: APK was built for a different platform
       at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:253)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.staticInit(ReactBridge.java:24)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.<clinit>(ReactBridge.java:20)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeMap.<clinit>(NativeMap.java:22)
       at com.facebook.react.JSCConfig$1.getConfigMap(JSCConfig.java:14)
       at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl.recreateReactContextInBackgroundFromBundleLoader(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:423)
       at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:419)
       at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl.createReactContextInBackground(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:363)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.startReactApplication(ReactRootView.java:213)
       at com.eightfit.app.ui.fragments.ReactFragment.startReactApp(ReactFragment.java:107)
       at com.eightfit.app.ui.fragments.ReactFragment.onViewCreated(ReactFragment.java:88)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1123)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:619)
       at com.eightfit.app.ui.activities.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:150)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app-lib/com.eightfit.app-1/libreactnativejni.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40
       at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:333)
       at java.lang.System.load(System.java:512)
       at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibraryFrom(DirectorySoSource.java:71)
       at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibrary(DirectorySoSource.java:42)
       at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:299)
       at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:247)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.staticInit(ReactBridge.java:24)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.<clinit>(ReactBridge.java:20)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeMap.<clinit>(NativeMap.java:22)
       at com.facebook.react.JSCConfig$1.getConfigMap(JSCConfig.java:14)
       at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl.recreateReactContextInBackgroundFromBundleLoader(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:423)
       at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:419)
       at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl.createReactContextInBackground(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:363)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.startReactApplication(ReactRootView.java:213)
       at com.eightfit.app.ui.fragments.ReactFragment.startReactApp(ReactFragment.java:107)
       at com.eightfit.app.ui.fragments.ReactFragment.onViewCreated(ReactFragment.java:88)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1123)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:619)
       at com.eightfit.app.ui.activities.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:150)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

In gradle we define Android NDK abi filter this way

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "mips", "x86"
}
```

We use React Native `0.35.0-rc.0` but we've been getting same crash also with stable release `0.33.1`.

Asus devices affected use cpu abi `armeabi-v7a`. Most other devices with same abi seems working fine.

[image]

You can find full crash report here.
https://gist.github.com/sealskej/5fc0c8e9092721d2be43b4d1ff3c60de

Any help leading to fixing issue would be much appreciated!

Comment: Those ASUS devices are all x86-based, but can probably run ARM code through libhoudini. Perhaps there was a mismatch in which variant of two libraries that the app attempted to load. This seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754468/running-android-native-code-is-causing-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror

Comment: @sealskej, any news?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as you. And I found that you should provide libraries optimized for each ABIs if possible, but it’s all in or nothing: you shall not mix. You have to provide the full set of the libraries you’re using in each ABI folder.In my project in armeabi-v7a dictionary are 32 .so files,but in x86 dictionary are 31 .so files.So the SoLoader may load the wrong file in x86 devices. You can see this [link](https://ph0b.com/android-abis-and-so-files/) to learn more